# DataGridView does not allow mouse go outside it when resizing a cloumn

Tags: datagridview, resize

i have a DataGridView and it has some columns , i want that it is possible to resize the column width , but DataGridView would not allow the last column bigger , when mouse reached the edge of it.
how can i fix this problem ?
i saw DataGridView in other softwares and i can drag the edge of last column and move it outside the control so that i can make it bigger , but somehow this control of .net has this dirty limit !
please share your solution 
thanks.

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/datagridview-last-column-can-made-smaller-but-not-bigger-t3059647.html... Looks like this is a common limitation.

Comment: i saw that link before i asked this question.but i didn't find a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can't do that but there's some dirty solution too :)

add a button to your form and put this code in the button click function

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width += 100;
```

Comment: well , it seems i must use ListView istead of DataGridView

Comment: yes, but the `DataGridView` is much better than `ListView` but in all it depends in your purpose:)

Comment: istead of using button , i used ContentMenu for its Columns and it does what you told me (dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width += 100;) , and that is how i solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a horizontally oriented splitcontainer control and dock it on your form.
Add the data grid to the left panel of the splitcontainer and dock it or anchor it so the right side is hard against the splitter position.
Then when the splitter of the splitcontainer is moved your grid will resize and you can handle 
the resize event to change column sizes.